# How to fix uncompleted sent message by c# socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I wrote a simple socket program with c# to send some parameters.

I defined my Byte variables like:

```
            byte[] BytedNetworkString = new byte[1024 * 10000];
            byte[] BytedNetworkFile = new byte[1024 * 100000];
```

Then I encode string to byte like:

```
Networkbyted = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("config%" + Program.sessionapp + "%" + filep3.Ext + "%.avi");
```

Then i sent them via TCP/IP socket but the receiver does not receive my message completely.

My original byted message size is equal to 23 but receiver byted message size is equal to 10.

Here is my code :

Its how I defined my socket.

```
public static Socket PublicStream = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

```
Program.availsock.Send(Networkbyted); //how i send

len = TargetSocket.Receive(BytedNetworkString);
tmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BytedNetworkString, 0, len); //its how i receive
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're not showing enough code, but generally you can't expect to receive your message in one chunk. Instead you must keep reading until the expected number of bytes have been received.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Amen.. especially when casually dropping 100 megabytes of zeroes onto the wire! :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks how should I do that?

Comment: There are numerous examples on how to send data over TcpClient. Just google it.